Customize CK editor 5 Headings
I am using custom build ckeditor5 in react application. Want to customise the headings. How to create classes in react for this. Or can we directly inject styles in customised headings.
Not able to get how to declare class in react application globally.
Not able to get how to directly add styles instead of using class.

If you are trying to customize the toolbar, see https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/toolbar/toolbar.html#customization. They explain how to change icons and customize the tooltip.
If you are trying to customize the headings in the editor, see https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/style.html to add styles to the text typed in the editor.
In React, you can create any class by adding a classname attribute to your element, the same way you would add a class in HTML. You can then use it in your main CSS or other stylesheet file.

Could you [edit] your answer to include the key points from the links you shared? If they go stale at some point,  it's hard for other people with the same issue to read up on the solution.
